# How to correctly send a json to a RestController using ajax?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, rest

I am trying to send a json to an api, but I get this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'status': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```

This is the javascript:

```
$("body").on('click','.btn-danger' ,(function (){
    var id = $(this).val();
    var data = {"status": "canceled",
                "response": ""};
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax ({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/api/pendingrequests/' + id,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: data,
        dataType : "html"
    }).done (function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
}));
```

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/pendingrequests/{requestId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity updateRequestStatus(@PathVariable Long requestId, @RequestBody HolidayRequestAction action) throws IOException {
        return updateRequestStatusService.updateRequest(requestId, action);
    }
```

And POJO which I am trying to receive from the request:

```
public class HolidayRequestAction {
    private String status;
    private String response;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

Why do I get this Parsing Exception ? What could be the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried passing a JSON string instead of an object? `var data = '{"status":"canceled","response":""}';`

Comment: Isn't the error pretty descriptive already ? token 'status': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'), mean that status property in data should either be true/false/null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question contains the answer: `'status': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')`

So you can  not send other values then `'true', 'false' or 'null'`

But in the request goes `"status": "canceled"`